# How Option<&T> implement Copy

Tags: rust, borrow-checker, ownership

I noticed something weird about the map function of Option<&T> and Option<T>,
after a quick googling, there is someone else noticed the same issue, as described in
[this question](https://users.rust-lang.org/t/why-does-map-takes-ownership-of-option-in-option-t-but-not-in-option-t/90351/7).
I will just use the same example.

```
let greet: Option<String> = Some("hi".to_string());

let mapped = greet.map(|e|e);

dbg!(mapped);
dbg!(greet);
```

the error message is :

```
use of moved value: `greet` ....
```

on the other hand, the following code is ok.

```
let greet: Option<String> = Some("hi".to_string());

let mapped = greet.as_ref().map(|e|e);

dbg!(mapped);
dbg!(greet);
```

the type of map function is:

```
pub const fn map<U, F>(self, f: F) -> Option<U>
```

So the ownership of the caller should be transferred to the `self' in map, and the explanation from that [question](https://users.rust-lang.org/t/why-does-map-takes-ownership-of-option-in-option-t-but-not-in-option-t/90351) is "Option<&T> implements Copy".

therefore, Option<T> transfers the ownership thus cause the error, while Option<&T> just create a new copy.

However, I cannot find anywhere that shows "Option<&T> implements Copy",
the worse thing is this, from the [document](https://doc.rust-lang.org/src/core/option.rs.html#560) :

```
/// The `Option` type. See [the module level documentation](self) for more.
#[derive(Copy, PartialOrd, Eq, Ord, Debug, Hash)]
#[rustc_diagnostic_item = "Option"]
#[cfg_attr(not(bootstrap), lang = "Option")]
#[stable(feature = "rust1", since = "1.0.0")]
pub enum Option<T> {
    /// No value.
    #[lang = "None"]
    #[stable(feature = "rust1", since = "1.0.0")]
    None,
    /// Some value of type `T`.
    #[lang = "Some"]
    #[stable(feature = "rust1", since = "1.0.0")]
    Some(#[stable(feature = "rust1", since = "1.0.0")] T),
}
```

It seems like Option<T> derived Copy trait, so the first example should be fine.

Did I miss anything from the module-level documentation?

Comment: https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/option/enum.Option.html#impl-Copy-for-Option%3CT%3E, `impl<T> Copy for Option<T> where T: Copy` and `&T` is always `Copy`.

Comment: Deriving Copy implies that Option<T> is Copy if T is copy. Since shared references are Copy, Option<&Anything> is Copy.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using `#[derive(Copy)]` includes a `T: Copy` constraint. Meaning that `Option<T>` only implements `Copy` if `T` implements `Copy`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for explain! So, can I understand it like this: since all borrowed references &T implement Copy, Option<&T> naturally implement Copy for free through derive?